# Internet sharing with 5 users

Tags: wireless-networking

i want to have 5 users connect to a router to use internet with their own SSID and assign each one of them about 3gb of data, once they finish their data, they will no longer have access to the net, but the ones who have data left can still use it...

To narrow my question .

I have a broadband which is connected to a router, through this network i want 5 people to connect through their SSID and each have it's own data limit. Can this be done in home basis without the need for having a dedicated Pc.

Comment: This requires expensive hardware very few products found in retail stores supoprt features like this.  There are open source solutions but the hardware those solutions work on are limited.  We cannot suggest products here at Superuser.

Comment: The question doesn't ask for product recommendations; it states a requirement and implicitly asks how this can be done.  A homebrew solution could be built with inexpensive commodity hardware.

Comment: @Flup - I maintain my stance this was asking for products since the author provided no evidence of doing research on captive portal software.

Comment: @flup Although you are correct in that this doesn't ask for product recommendations, it also doesn't contain a question either. It's actually a statement. Ramhound didn't say the question asked for a recommendation, rather provided the fact that it's not allowed. As many of us do, this is to help the poster.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you will need

- a wireless access point
- a captive portal to authenticate the users when they start using the network
- a firewall to prevent traffic passing to unauthenticated users, or those who have exhausted their bandwidth allowance

The latter two could be hosted on a small PC or embedded device.  Open-source captive portal software is available (e.g. [WiFiDog](http://wifidog.org/), although this might be a bit heavyweight for what you want).

It's likely you'll have to write your own script to monitor each user's traffic levels and ensure that they can't log in for the rest of the day.  You'll need a reasonable understanding of how all this stuff works, but as a homebrew project I'd say that was of intermediate difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

A relatively easier solution could be using [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index)

A tutorial for accomplishing such with single SSID
http://www.kczon.com/bandwidth-limit-wrt-script-generator/

Google can reveal way more.